# Chat and data structure integration

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, node.js, websocket

I'm planing on building a sort of "team chat" for my company and to, probably, integrate it later with some of our applications/websites.

After some "light" reading I decided to use Node.js and socketIO rather than just long polling in php.

So, my doubt is, should i build a more complex app in JS (with MVC) or just use it to handle the message delivering system? I mean, I already have the MVC application in php, i have my data structure defined, and what i really need is just the websockets.

Should It:

- Handle the login in PHP
- Handle the Users and User associations (to other users, groups, rooms, etc...) in PHP
- Send the view (html, js, css, etc...) to the Client
- Handle the "chat" logic in Node.js

Or should it:

- Handle "everything" in Node.js, replicating the necessary models in JS (Users and users associations) and share the same Database between the Node.js and the PHP applications?

I feel like the second approach is the better one, but I would love to read some opinions on the matter.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If MVC is ready in PHP, I would recommend using NodeJS with SocketIO because it can automatically get to supported protocol, some browsers may not be supporting websockets.

Comment: NodeJS and SocketIO will be present in both ways. The difference will be how to handle the "business" logic (Logins, Users, Associations). Thank You.